# Google Sheets only return columns containing key word using arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a pivot table of info, with totals (the totals columns contain the word "Total").

I want to do some more processing with this data, so I created a new sheet.
The new sheet first has

`=arrayformula('Pivot Table mins'!A:B)`

to grab the first two columns.

But then I want to "import" over JUST the columns that have the word Total in them.

e.g. if the Pivot Table data spans columns A to Z, but only columns D & F have the keyword "Total", I only want to "import" those columns.

I could do a query, but then I'd have to have a huge query (e.g. I'd have to have ..."C contains 'total' OR D contains 'total'..." etc...all the way to Z, I believe)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

## Case #1. Some columns

The first option is to build `query`

The second option is to use `filter`:

`=FILTER(Sheet!A:G,(REGEXMATCH(Sheet!D:D,"Total"))+(REGEXMATCH(Sheet!F:F,"Total")))`

---

Plus `+` in the formula means `OR` logic.

`Regexmatch` us used to make sure column contains the string.

**Edit**

You may also shorten the formula to:

`=FILTER(Sheet!A:G,(REGEXMATCH(Sheet!D:D&Sheet!F:F,"Total")))`

It works because `Sheet!D:D&Sheet!F:F` concatenates 2 columns so if any contains "Total", the `filter` will find it.

## Case #2. Any column from range

Answer to the comment:

> Is there a way to do that for all columns? That's my problem...the
>   columns with the word "Total" changes.

`=FILTER('Sheet'!A:M,MMULT(--REGEXMATCH('Sheet'!A:L,"Total"),ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&COLUMNS('Sheet'!A:L)))^0))`

used mmult to convert 2d array of `true/false` values into single line. Now any row from `A:L` where some column contains "Total" will be returned as a result.

Comment: Is there a way to do that for *all* columns? That's my problem...the columns with the word "Total" changes. And I don't want to do Sheet!D:D&Sheet!E:E&Sheet!F:F... etc. Is there a way to do something like ......REGEXMATCH(Sheet!A:Z,"Total")?